# Lexicographic sort using provided character set

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I understand the logic behind performing a lexicographic sort and how to code it in a simple way. I do not know how to do it when presented with this function signature

```
void sort_lexicographically(char *phrase, char const *alphabet);
```

where both arguments are strings.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should attempt this problem on your own first, and post your best attempt here when you truly get stuck. As is, we can only speculate as to what the input and expected output of your program is - there is very little useful information here, and we need more information to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the function signature, there's only one sensible interpretation of what the function is supposed to do: sort the characters in the string `phrase` in-place according to the collation order defined by `alphabet`. This can be done e. g. with a table containing the sorting position of each character.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char ord[CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN+1];

int compar(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ord[*(char *)a-CHAR_MIN]-ord[*(char *)b-CHAR_MIN];
}

void sort_lexicographically(char *phrase, char const *alphabet)
{
    memset(ord, 0, sizeof ord); // all characters not in alphabet get order 0
    int o = 0;  // collating order, increasingly assigned to alphabet characters
    while (*alphabet) ord[*alphabet++-CHAR_MIN] = ++o;
    qsort(phrase, strlen(phrase), 1, compar);
}

int main()
{
    char phrase[] = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    puts(phrase);
    sort_lexicographically(phrase, "aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz");
    puts(phrase);
}
```